# Grep display both matched and umatched lines

Tags: linux, grep

How can I use `grep` command to display both matched and unmatched lines? Matched line should be in red and other lines should be in normal color.

Is there a `grep` option available to do that?

Comment: Try `grep "pattern" filename --color=always`

Comment: try `man grep`, the answer is hard to miss even if you put in minimal effort

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907702/grep-display-both-matched-and-unmatched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep --color=always -e pattern -e '$'
```

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: This does not work for me, matched pattern is not colored. Any suggestion? My `$TERM` is `vt100`.

Comment: @Gnouc, the vt100 terminal is monochrome. The first DEC terminal to support colors [was VT241](http://www.vt100.net/vt_history). But I doubt you're using a real VT100 terminal. In any case GNU `grep` doesn't use `$TERM`, it hardcodes the ANSI escape sequences (regardless of whether your terminal supports (or claims to support) them or not). If `grep 'x\|$'` works, so should `grep -e X -e '^'` though. Also, check your environment for `GREP_COLOR` or `GREP_COLORS` variables.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Suprising, `grep 'x\|$'` works but `grep -e X -e '^'`, `GREP_COLOR` and `GREP_COLORS` both are null. I'm on Windows machine, using `Secure Shell client` to connect to my Linux Server.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, after testing, I see that `grep -e X -e '^'` works but `grep -e '^' -e X` like your answer does not.

Comment: @Gnouc, which version of grep is that? I've updated the answer.

Comment: `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`

Comment: @Gnouc, interestingly `grep --color -e x -e '^'` segfaults in OS/X (FreeBSD grep 2.5.1) but not with `$`, so I've updated the answer once again for better portability.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Do you have any ideal why `grep --color -e x -e '^'` cause a segfaults?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep --color=always -e 'pattern\|$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match other lines to have some context, you can use the `-A` and `-B` options:

```
grep --color=always -A 9 -B 9 -e pattern
```

will give you 9 lines of context. If this is not sufficient, you can increase this value.